# url rewrite both www to non-www and delete parameter index.php?url when use phpmvc

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect `www.myDomain.com/index.php?url=controller/methode/parameter` to
`mayDomain.com/controller/methode/parameter`

this is my htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

the problem is when use www at the beginning url, `index.php?url=` appear in url !
is there any way to do not show this?

Answer (score 0):

Your directives are in the wrong order. Your canonical redirect needs to be *before* your internal rewrite.

To delete the URL parameter you need an additional redirect. However, this assumes that your internal URLs all use the canonical format, ie. `/controller/methode/parameter`. (The redirect is only for any backlinks.)

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove "url" parameter if requested directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=([^&])*
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Canonical www to non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is necessary to prevent a rewrite loop, since we only want to redirect direct requests and not requests that have already been rewritten.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.